# Android Simulator - very slow

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

I would like to use an Android SDK Simulator to debug a website but the time that it's loading is not acceptable. It's like 5 minutes. I can refresh a website 100 times on Apple XCode Simulator (and on actual iPhone as well) during Android SDK loading time.

Furthermore, all the icons inside lag. It's completely not usable. 
[image]

So, I come to conclusion that it shouldn't be like that but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong? I just installed it, I installed all the newest components, I'm on i7, 8GB RAM computer and it lags from the very beginning. I can't even type a website address without having to wait 60 seconds - not to mention, debug anything. Can anyone shed some light on that?

Comment: By any chance not an Android device laying around? Much, Much faster.

Comment: Yes, Android device = perfect, fast, smooth. Android Simulator = crap.

Comment: I belive it should do better.  Something sounds wrong but I don't know what.  I remember browsing around a few websites being suprised how quick it was a 14 months back before I had a real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're emulating a Linux OS, and on top of that it's running a Java Virtual Machine, and on top of that, it's running the android application, which is finally running your application. All of these steps are highly memory intense, and therefore, you'll experience slow running times of your application because of it. As suggested in the comments, the fastest way to debug the application is with an Android device itself. When testing times, it's far better to do so on an actual Android device than off of a separate machine, purely due to the amount of emulation that it does which will slow down execution.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. So perhaps running this on Linux will help? I can do that. But I don't understand why can't they support Windows or Mac? Any sane developer uses one of those. iOS simulator is smooth.

Comment: Android is based on the idea that the underlying OS behind the JVM is Linux, and it even gives you some Linux commands you can run. It assumes that the file structure as well conforms to the Linux specifications, so that's why you can't just load Android right up off a Windows or Mac, since they use different file structures.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the ARM emulator. Try the  Intel x86 emulator for a much faster emulator. 
It's included in the Android 4.0.3 SDK.

Comment: Thanks! That's going to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another way to make the emulator work much better, although I'm using windows so not sure if it will work in the same way.

If you go into the AVD Manager (where you manage your android virtual devices) and edit the one that has the slow problem. Near the bottom there is an option to use host GPU. Tick this option and makes a vast improvement on the speed of the emulator.

I found the emulator pretty unusable until I tried this

Comment: I had this set to "Emulate GPU" and after turning this off it got a bit better. I'm on a laptop - maybe that's a problem. Laptops are generally slow. I'm on Windows 7. I use emulated MAC to run XCode and XCode emulator works just fine. Anyway, I think I'll start using real device then. Thank for your help!

Comment: That's strange, real devices are better to work on if possible, maybe it depends on the hardware as I've tried it on my laptop and desktop (both AMD CPUs, different types obviously) but the improvement was still there (although laptop does start to cook my knees slightly :))